# When clicking the button, the content doesn't change. - Android

Tags: java, android

I want to change the content on a button change, but it never works.

```
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setContentView(R.layout.blahdyblah);
            }
        });
```

So that's the code, but whenever I want to change setContentView(), it doesn't change, it just clicks and does nothing. If anyone could help me in this task...

I've also tried putting the setContentView in another function... That still doesn't work.

Comment: Why are you trying to change the content view of the `Activity` if it has already been set?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to change one content to another by a button...

Comment: I can see from the code that you're trying to set the content view.  My question is why are you doing it this way?  This approach is unlikely to work successfully, so I'm trying to get a handle on why you would want to do that, so I know whether to recommend a separate `Activity` or `Fragments` or showing/hiding of existing `Views`.  What behavior are you trying to produce by changing the content view?

Comment: AFAIK, it's legal and reasonable to change your activity's entire content view.  For example, I have a calculator app that lets you swap between full scientific and basic. Since the functionality is identical either way (just fewer displayed buttons in basic view), there's no point is launching a new activity, so I simply change the content view.  It's worked perfectly on every release from 1.0 on.

Comment: @EdwardFalk Yes, it can work successfully.  It's also a fairly common approach for new-to-Android developers to take who don't yet know the lifecycle and are actually attempting to change Activities.  The fact that Corecase's answer was accepted is indicative of this.  I was just trying to figure out which sort of case this is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you want your screen to switch to another layout when the button is clicked.  Try the following.  First of all, make an activity called "blahdyblah" instead of just an xml file(So you should have two activities, your main activity which has the button with the onClickListener, and a separate activity called "blahdyblah").  After you've done that, try this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, blahdyblah.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
});
```

In the code, replace "MainActivity" with the name of the class in which you are writing this onClickListener.

Set the blahdyblah.java file's content view to `R.layout.blahdyblah`
I'm pretty sure that should do what you're looking for.

blahdyblah.java

```
public class blahdyblah extends Activity
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.blahdyblah);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try ActivityName.this.setContentView(R.layout.blahdyblah) where ActivityName is your activity? It could be that setContentView is called on the context you are currently dealing with.. which inside your button onclick is the button

If that does not work could you please edit your answer to display your entire code

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest;
1) make sure the button is in the same context / class if where your current view is
2) make sure your 'blahdyblah' is a properly set up XML file

You may also want to start a new activity, in which you can setContentView -- perhaps there is a problem changing the content in your current activity.

Comment: Yep. I've checked it. It is a proper XML file. And why would I click something that isn't there...

Comment: These are possible problems I could foresee with the limited code you posted up. I meant if your button was part of another context, apart from your current Activity or context, it might not change your current view correctly. Try not to expect a perfectly detailed answer when you've literally posted nothing about the situation of your setContentView method call.

Comment: Your "chosen" answer was already suggested in my initial post
"You may also want to start a new activity, in which you can setContentView"

read closer next time.

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way:

```
{
    ...
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setBlahdyBlah();
        }
    });
}

...

private void setBlahdyBlah() {
    setContentView(R.layout.blahdyblah);
}
```

This will guarantee that your call to setContentView() is executed from the right context.

I'm not exactly sure why it didn't work the way you wrote it, but I think your code depends on your OnClickListener having been created as a proper inner class of the Activity, and that the global 'R' be correctly accessible from that scope.  I'm not sure where it failed, but my way eliminates the unknowns from this problem.  Plus, that's how I did it and it worked for me.

Hmmm, upon further consideration, I bet this would work too:

```
    final Activity foo = this;
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            foo.setContentView(R.layout.blahdyblah);
        }
    });
```

I think it's all related to your OnClickListener not being a proper inner class of your activity.